# Only chose 'Online' if it is the latest date in the database

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

| ID | Status | Online Datestamp | Other Datestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Online | 2022-07-01 |  |
| 1 | Offline | NULL | 2022-08-01 |
| 2 | Online | 2022-08-03 |  |
| 2 | Unknown |  | 2022-07-01 |
| 3 | Online | 2022-07-03 |  |
| 3 | Online | 2022-07-05 |  |
| 3 | Unknown | NULL | 2022-06-05 |
| 4 | Unknown | NULL | 2022-06-02 |
| 5 | Online | 2022-04-04 |  |
| 5 | Online | 2022-04-06 |  |

The output I'm looking for in SQL/BigQuery.

| ID | Status | Online Datestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Online | 2022-08-03 |
| 3 | Online | 2022-07-05 |
| 5 | Online | 2022-04-06 |

So what SQL query I would want to return is the rows for ID 2,3 & 5 as the **newest status** for that ID is "Online". I only care about getting the rows for IDs that have 'Online' as their newest row.

ID 1 **should not** be included even though they have one "online" status. As they have **an offline status at a newer date.**

Furthemore, **ID 2 should be included** as their online datestamp is newer than the unknown datestamp.

ID 3 should be included as Online is the latest timestamp for that ID. Which is the same for ID 5.

I am only looking for IDs which have Online as their **latest** status.

I'm finding it difficult as I need to compare between two columns, any thoughts would be appreciated.

But if it is easier, I wouldn't mind an output showing all columns if Online is the only Status, for example. (including all rows of ID 3 and 5).

| ID | Status | Online Datestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Online | 2022-08-03 |
| 3 | Online | 2022-07-03 |
| 3 | Online | 2022-07-05 |
| 5 | Online | 2022-04-04 |
| 5 | Online | 2022-04-06 |

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (mysql or google-bigquery)? Those are two very different platforms and the SQL dialect will differ significantly.

Comment: Bigquery initially then coding via dbt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **HAVING** along with **ARRAY_AGG**,

```sql
SELECT id, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(status, Online_Datestamp) ORDER BY Online_Datestamp DESC LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)].*
  FROM sample_table, UNNEST([Online_Datestamp, Other_Datestamp]) Online_Datestamp
 GROUP BY id
HAVING status = 'Online';
```

You can get the result following:

[image]

Note: You may need type casting for **datestamp**s like **SAFE_CAST(Online_Datestamp AS DATE)** depending on data in your real table.

Answer (score 1):

You can carry it out with a `ROW_NUMBER` window function inside a `QUALIFY` clause. In order to handle the two column dates, you can use the `COALESCE` function.

```
SELECT ID,
       Status,
       Online Datestamp
FROM tab
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY COALESCE(OnlineTimestamp, OtherTimestamp) DESC) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider below option

```
select * from your_table
where status != 'Unknown'
qualify countif(status != 'Online') over (partition by id)= 0   
and row_number() over (partition by id order by Online_Datestamp desc) = 1
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

> But if it is easier, I wouldn't mind an output showing all columns if Online is the only Status,

Note: if you remove line with row_number - output will be

[image]